# Find all continuous functions (did I do this correctly?)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Find all the continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying:
>
> $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Solution attempt:

$$\begin{align*}
f(x+y) + 1 &= f(x) + f(y) + f(x)f(y) + 1\\
f(x+y) + 1 &= (f(x) + 1)(f(y) + 1)
\end{align*}$$

$g(x) = f(x) + 1$, and $g(y) = f(y) + 1$

$$\begin{align*}
g(x+y) &= g(x)g(y)\\
(x,y) &= (x,x)\\
g(2x) &= g^2(x)\\
g(x) &= g^2(x/2)\\
g(x) &= c^x,\;\text{ where }c = e^a
\end{align*}$$

So $f(x) = c^x - 1$ for all x

Comment: LaTeX tips: use `\mathbb{R}` to get $\mathbb{R}$, use `\to` to get $\to$, use `\in` to get $\in$, and use the `align` environment to get a centered array of aligned equations, one after another. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: It is correct. But you have to give the reason why you got $g(x)=c^x$ from $g(x)=g^2(x/2)$.

Comment: The inroduction of $g$ is good. The $c=e^a$ is mysterious and not quite right. We need a proof that the only continuous solutions of the functional equation for $g$ are the stated ones. One indication that there might be a gap is that you have not used continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result is correct, however, there is a gap in proving that $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$ implies that $g(x)=c^x$.

First of all, $g(x)=g^2(\frac{x}{2})$ implies that $g(0)=0$ , or $g(0)=1$.

- If $g(0)=0$ then $f(0)=-1$ and using the given relationship for $y=0, x\in \mathbb R$, we get:

$$f(x+0)=f(x)+f(0)+f(x)f(0)\Rightarrow f(x)=f(x)-1-f(x)\Rightarrow f(x)=-1,\forall x\in \mathbb R$$

- Now, If $g(0)=1$ , we have to follow some steps in order to reach the
  desired conclusion:

  1. For $n\in\mathbb N$ it is easy to see that $$g(n)=g(1+\dots+1)=g(1)\times\dots\times g(1)=[g(1)]^n$$
  2. Also note that $$g(1+(-1))=g(1)g(-1)\Rightarrow g(0)=g(1)g(-1)\Rightarrow g(-1)=\dfrac{1}{g(1)}=[g(1)]^{-1}$$
  3. Now for a negative integer $-m$ we have :
     $$g(-m)=g(-1\dots-1)=g(-1)\times\dots\times g(-1)=[g(1)]^{-m}$$
  4. Next, prove it for $\dfrac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb N$. You have already proved that $g(2x)=g^2(x).$ If you extend this, you can easily get $g(nx)=g^n(x)$. So for $x=\frac{1}{n}$
     $$g^n(\frac{1}{n})=g(1)\Rightarrow g(\frac{1}{n})=[g(1)]^{1/n}$$
  5. Now the big step: Prove it for rationals $\dfrac{m}{n}$
     $$g(\frac{m}{n})=g(\frac{1}{n}+\dots+\frac{1}{n})=g(\frac{1}{n})\times\dots\times g(\frac{1}{n})=g(\frac{1}{n})^m=[[g(1)]^{1/n}]^m=[g(1)]^{m/n}$$
  6. Finally, if you take a  $x\in\mathbb R$, then there exists a sequence of rationals $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $q_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty}x$ and:
     $$g(x)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(q_n)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}[g(1)]^{q_n}=[g(1)]^x$$
     where we used the continuity of $g$ as well as the continuity of the exponential function.

So we reached the desired result : $$g(x)=[g(1)]^x=c^x$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x)=g(x)-1=c^x-1$$
(or $f(x)=-1$ do not forget!)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially yes, except that it's not immediately clear, as xpaul notes, that $g(x)=c^x$ follows from the previous line, especially since you didn't mention continuity. (Given you have $c=e^a$ but no mention of $a$, I suspect you left something out!)

---

Personally I proceed from $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$ by noticing $g(x)=g(x/2)^2\ge 0$ so either $g(x) = 0$ (and $f(x) = -1$ - note that if this happens at one point, it happens everywhere; why?) or
$$h(x)=\ln g(x) \quad \implies \quad h(x+y) = h(x) + h(y) \quad \implies \quad h(nx) = nh(x)$$

What next? *Hint*: Given any $x\in\mathbb R$ notice that we can approximate $x\approx \frac{m}{n}$ by a rational number. *Answer below*.

---

By making this approximation with some accuracy, $x-\frac{m}{n} = \delta$, we find
$$h(x) = h\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) + h(\delta) = m h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) + h(\delta) = \frac{m}{n} h(1) + h(\delta) = x h(1) + h(\delta) - \delta h(1)$$
This is all exact. Use the continuity of $h$, making $\delta$ nice and small, and you find $h(x) = x h(1)$ which gives you the result you need. I'll leave you to fill in the details.

---

You can definitely do this in lots of ways; this is just the one which comes most naturally to my mind.

Comment: Haha, I did somehow leave out two lines when trying to learn how to format my post (first time posting here, so I was playing around with it trying to quickly read up on it while posting).

Thanks for the verification/help everyone :)